# elasticsearch query for (A AND NOT B) OR (C AND NOT D)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to achieve `(A exists AND B does not exist) OR (C exists AND D does not exist)` in an ElasticSearch query.

I have what feels like a poor (verbose, unclear to read) solution, which I will post as an answer.

What is the best (clearest, most readable) way to achieve an `(A AND NOT B) OR (C AND NOT D)` query?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the question, this is the initial attempt which seems to work but seems unnecessarily verbose.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "A"
                 }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                 {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "B"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }

        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "C"
                 }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                 {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "D"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }

        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```